# What methods are called by which scene's objects on start?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to check **what methods** exactly are called on scene's start? And **which objects** called them? I want to achieve something similar to adding `Debug.Log();` to every single method but without doing it. I'd like to know what's going on in a project when I press play.

Comment: i think this should help https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: Not exactly what I meant ;) I know what's the method's order. I just need to find out what "custom" methods (present in objects on the scene) are being called when I play the scene.

Comment: I don't mean just opening the scene in the editor. I mean clicking "Play", so I guess starting the game then?

Comment: Can you do something without doing it? No, of course not ^^ Either add the `Debug.Log` which gives you a complete stacktrace so you see exactly where the call originated from or [Debug your code with breakpoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) which achieves the same but without the need of changing the code .. you can basically add the breakpoints adhoc anywhere you need one

Comment: Note that logging too much stuff can extremely slow down the application even in a build since they get written including the stacktrace to the log file .. so be careful what to log and what not ..

Answer (score 0):

A scene consists only of game objects (there's nothing else in Unity).

GameObjects may have 1 or more `Component`s attached.

When you click Play ...

It looks like you already know that, the calls such as

```
void Start()
```

(if they exist in the script) are called - automatically, by Unity - when each `Component` on each `GameObject` is launched with the scene.

It's quite common that inside each Start, you just add something like Debug.Log("starting, script name, on .. " + transform.name) which will simply let you know that that component on that game object has started.

Maybe that's what you need.

Obviously you will have added many functions to your own scripts

```
void SomeFunction() {
```

Are you saying you want to know **when those functions run**?

If so the only way to do that is simply manually add a Debug line, inside each function.

(Regarding functions which you add yourself, example `SomeFunction`, they are **not** in any way called automatically. They are only called if you call them (say from `Start` or similar).  You can be sure they are only called if you call them.

Comment: Ok, that is clear. But let's say I have a scene with dozens of GameObjects. And those GameObjects have multiple methods and functions that are being called somewhere in the code. And that's why I need to find out what functions are being called by what GameObjects without checking it in code. Is it possible without debugging it manually?

Comment: No, you do it manually by adding Debug.Log statements!